# Tabulator - Money formatter exported as string in excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, tabulator, currency-formatting

I have tabulator grid and it has some currency values, but when exporting them to excel, excel formulas are not working.

```
 formatter: "money",
  formatterParams: {
    decimal: ",",
    thousand: ".",
    symbol: "$",
    precision: 2,
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zv30o5e1/1/

So please let me know how to use that, I need thousand separator and $ as prefix in excel.

Thanks,
Laxmi Lal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track by using the `accessorDownload` option.  One way would be to use `Intl.NumberFormat()` method to convert the value string to US dollars ($ prefix).  Here is an example forked from your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4u7zet1/

**UPDATE**

If you need to set the Number format at Excel level, then instead of using `accessorDownload`, this can be done by modifying the workbook with SheetJS methods during tabulator export using `documentProcessing` callback.

You can loop thru tabulator data and set the format, based on SheetJS number formats (https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/csf/features/nf#currency), to each cell of the column you need. Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vtcheu75/1/

Comment: Thank you, but still issue is same. Excel shows number as text, I think there is a MSO style but how to add at accessorDownload.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.  Please see my updated answer.  Maybe this will help.

Comment: I have dynamic multiple tabulator grids, and data are also  dynamic.. all sheets exported to single excel. 

https://jsfiddle.net/nduLwq1z/1/

Please let me know how to handle it with this sheets array.

Comment: You can loop thru the tables to generate a single file with multiple sheets from each table: https://jsfiddle.net/g97p4nv2/